# Is there a way to deploy an app onto the google play store but the ability to push out any updates without going through the google play store?

Tags: android, deployment

I need to find a way to push out updates to our app, but need it to happen instantly, instead of a 24 hour period or whatever it may take normally.

So at the moment we have an app that is just a WebView inside an app container, so we can update instantly because we only need to update the website and the app is automatically updated, but we want to transition to a native app which means we will need to redeploy every time we make an update. This will slow down our development and increase deployment times.

Is there an option which will give us the freedom to have a native app and create updates without having to redeploy through the google play store each time, or if we do have to use the store is there a way to have a faster turn around time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing some research it's possbile ,if you would like to check if you app has updates (without interacting with Google Play), you'd have to poll a server (providing your current version) and let the server check if there is a newer version available. If that is the case, let the server respond with a changelog and an url to the newer version.

Luckily, there are libraries to do this:

[AppUpdater](https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater). Android Library that checks for updates on your own server (or Google Play, Github, etc). Great [documentation](https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater/wiki/UpdateFrom.JSON). This library notifies your apps' updates by showing a Material dialog, Snackbar or notification.

[AppUpdateChecker](https://github.com/mitmel/AppUpdateChecker) A simple non-Market way to keep your app updated. All it requires to set up is a URL pointing to a JSON document describing your app's changes.

[Auto Updater](https://github.com/NDMAC/android-auto-updater-client) This project allows to automatically update a running APK application using a private update server (see [apk-updater](https://github.com/NDMAC/apk-updater)) instead of Google Play updater. Also comes with a server script.

[SmartUpdates](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidSmartUpdates). Older library, but instructions in English and also provides a server script.